# React Testing Library + Vitest mocking React child component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library, vitest

I am trying to test if a parent component renders children. I hit a wall trying to mock child component inside the test file.
It seems like nothing is being mocked, and I don't understand why.
I just want to return a `div` with `testid` and check if it is being rendered.
I have read that it is the best to mock and just test if it renders, because I am testing the child components separately.

My file structure looks like this:

[image]

Child looks like this:

```ts
export function Child() {
  return <div>Child</div>;
}
```

All Children are exported from the `index.ts` file inside the nested `components` folder in the `Parent` directory:

```ts
export * from './Child';
export * from './Child2';
```

And imported inside the Parent to render them:

```ts
import { Child, Child2 } from './components';

export function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child />
      <Child2 />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Test file:

```ts
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

vi.mock('./components', () => ({
  Child: () => <div data-testid="child" />,
}));

describe('Parent', () => {
  it('should render Child', () => {
    render(<Parent />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('child')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  screen.debug();
});
```

`screen.debug()` logs the normal `Child` component content, not the mocked one. What am I missing?

My Vite config:

```ts
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: './src/tests/setupTests.ts',
  },
});
```

And the `setupTests.ts` file:

```ts
import { server } from '@/__mocks__';
import { cleanup } from '@/tests/utils';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import * as matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';
import { expect } from 'vitest';

expect.extend(matchers);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  server.resetHandlers();
});
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should replace:

```
vi.mock('./components', () => ({
  Child: () => <div data-testid="child" />,
}));
```

by

```
vi.mock('./components', async (importActual) => {
    const mod = await importActual<any>();

    return {
        ...mod,
        Child: () => <div data-testid="child" />,
    }; 
});
```

Doing that, you import a part of your code (ie. Child2) and you mock only Child